# use **/* in ant files when we specify the path

Tags: java, ant

Ant snippet generated from eclipse

I wanted to know what is meaning/significance of **/* in path why they can't have only *.java 
If they want to exclude java file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `**` is shorthand for "any nesting depth of directories (of any name)".

The `*` is shorthand for "any file (or directory)"

The `.java` is shorthand for "that ends with `.java`"

So, to recap `**/*.java` is any file, at any depth of the current directory tree, which ends in `.java`.

Comment: Excellently explained. + for nice answer.